# Is it possible to extend MacOS Terminal.app?

Tags: xcode, terminal, apple-developer

I am trying to find if it is possible to add functionality to the existing MacOS Terminal.app. Specifically I would like to add the possibility to slide in/out a little notes section that I could use to hold variables/ideas.

I've tried looking at the AppKit documentation on apples developer site which seems to point only to creating new apps not extending or adding functionality to new ones. I've searched github for existing extension (TotalCommand or Visor) but the last open source version is from 2013 and does not seem to apply to current MacOS programming procedures.

I am not interested in iTerm2 or other shells I need/want to use the default terminal.app.

Comment: The closest thing that comes to mind would be creating an Applescript routine that opened both terminal and a text file for the notes (Stickies, TextEdit...).

Comment: Thanks, that will work, Not as elegantly as I would have liked but its a start.